# Android HttpPost 403 error

Tags: android, python, django, django-rest-framework

i write android client for django rest framework. i use **ModelsViewSet** with django rest framework. when i try to create new user with my android client i receive this error:

**[08/Jan/2015 22:49:23] "POST /users/ HTTP/1.1" 403 59**

this is my android client code:

```
public class Test extends Activity {  

    String URL = "http://192.168.0.103:8000/users/";  
    String result = "";    


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
        /*
         *Make http call to the webservice
         */
        RequestTask ws = new RequestTask();
        ws.execute(URL);

    } // end onCreate()  

    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri[0]);

            try{
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "dinho"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_of_birth", "2013-12-11"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", "Male"));           
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", "tout choco"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
               response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                }else{

                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result!=null) {
                EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ws_test_field);
                et.setText(result);

                }
        }


    }

}
```

this is my ModelViewSet

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, permissions.AllowAny)
```

please help me i try to solve this step since 2 days. Thank for your help.

Comment: [http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#api-reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#api-reference)

Comment: @aschattney you think that it's csrf_token problem ?

Comment: Is there any way that you can get the body of the 403 response that is being returned? That's where it will tell you what the issue is.

Comment: @KevinBrown no there is any way to get the body of 403 response but i now is authentication or Permission error, but i d'ont know how i can solve it

Comment: yes i think you need to provide the token as a parameter or completely disable this middleware..

Comment: CSRF doesn't make sense for an android application, I'm not sure where you would bet getting the token...

Comment: @angel check this out!  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252360/android-sending-post-requests-to-django-server-csrf-failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252360/android-sending-post-requests-to-django-server-csrf-failing)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not able to view the body of the response that you are getting, your options for solving this are *very limited*. As you are getting a `403` error, we know this is either an authentication or authorization (permissions) issue.

You do not appear to be performing any authentication for the request, so most likely DRF is under the assumption that you are working with an anonymous user. Assuming this is correct, you most likely have a permissions issue.

You are using two permission classes, [`IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly) and [`AllowAny`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany). Because you are using `AllowAny` with another permission class, it has absolutely no effect and it could actually be removed without any issues. The `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` class limits the access of an anonymous user such that they [can only make `GET`, `OPTIONS`, or `HEAD` requests](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly) to endpoints. If you try to perform any other actions, such as `POST` request, it will reject it with a `403` error because the permission check failed.

The easiest way that you can fix this is by changing your permissions on the `ViewSet` to allow for anonymous creation of users.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        # Allow anonymous user registration
        if self.action == "create":
            return permissions.AllowAny()

        return permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly()
```

For this we override `get_permissions` instead of [implementing a new permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions). You may also want to [look into more complex permissions](http://richardtier.com/2014/02/25/django-rest-framework-user-endpoint/) to users modifying other's data.

Comment: it's weird but this error caused by permissions.AllowAny()

Answer (score 0):

```
i solve my problem by suppress permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly in permission classes and i have add headers parameter to my android post request my correct django source code is:

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

and i have add this to my android souce code:


my android final code souce is:
public class Test extends Activity {  

    String URL = "http://192.168.0.103:8000/users/";  
    String result = "";    


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
        /*
         *Make http call to the webservice
         */
        RequestTask ws = new RequestTask();
        ws.execute(URL);

    } // end onCreate()  

    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri[0]);

            try{
                httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("username", "abcd");
                obj.put("date_of_birth", "2013-12-11");
                obj.put("gender", "Male");
                obj.put("description", "tout choco");
                httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
               response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                }else{

                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result!=null) {
                EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ws_test_field);
                et.setText(result);

                }
        }


    }

}
```

thank all for your help !