# Android Calling Django Server With POST Data

Tags: android, django

someone may asked my question already but I cannot find any suggestions.

I writing an Android app which needs to access my `Django` server by using `HttpsURLConnection` then `Django` server will return a `JSON` array to Android.

The view function in `Django` will receive the parameters from request.POST and generate the `JSON` array then return using `HTTPResponse` Django method.  It does not need any Templates and Forms.

When I call the `Django` view function from Android, it returns 403 error.  I know that it is because the POST data does not contains "csrf_token".

My problem is:  How can I get the "csrf_token" and put it into my POST data before I send it to `Django`?  I try disable the CSRF checking by "@csrf_exempt" it can return the correct result to Android app but I would not disable the CSRF checking.

Thanks,
Wilson

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/17283820/2967875

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the cookies and also have to send a header 'X-CSRFToken' with csrftoken.

This is what I do (may not be the best way):

1. Get csrf token via a get request.But first try to see if you get a csrftoken cookie by doing same request on your browser with developer tools. If not, you should use ensure_csrf_cookie decorator

   ```
   from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
   @ensure_csrf_cookie
   def your_view(request):
       pass
   ```
2. Now using the same HttpUrlConnection object do this :

   ```
   String cookieString="";
   String csrftoken="";

   // The below code can be shortened using for-each loop
   List<HttpCookie> cookies=cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
   Iterator<HttpCookie> cookieIterator=cookies.iterator();
   while(cookieIterator.hasNext()){
       HttpCookie cookie=cookieIterator.next();
       cookieString+=cookie.getName()+"="+cookie.getValue()+";";
       if(cookie.getName().equals("csrftoken")){
           csrftoken=cookie.getValue();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the following to your post request:

   ```
   urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
   urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieString);
   ```